# Create table from object type

Tags: c#, dapper

I'm trying to figure out how I can create an empty table from an object type.
The type is quite simple (only primitive type properties); there's something ready to use?

Do I need to make to write my own "CREATE TABLE" query using some properties reflection?

I'm working on a project that reads data from a FirebirdSQL database and writes some of that tables in a Sqlite database, using Dapper.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I don't know of anything in dapper that does that, personally. Core "dapper" certainly doesn't, and I can't see anything in "Rainbow" or "Contrib".

Comment: @Marc, I built a base data model object and I linked to an example of that in my answer on this question. I wanted to start a little open source project that would leverage Dapper but also provide a simple but quick and robust way of building a data model that can construct the statements for you. It would need abstracted more so that you could have base models for different providers and such, but what do you think friend?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Marc stated, Dapper isn't going to do that for you, but have a look at my answer here ([ADO.NET distinct data bases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746050/ado-net-distinct-data-bases/15788258#15788258)) and simply adapt one of the command properties to construct a CREATE TABLE statement and it will leverage reflection. It should be pretty straight forward with that much of a head start.

I'd create an example, but I'm answering this from my phone.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion; it is just what I've done. Your linked answer is a plus, thanks.

Comment: @FerdinandoSantacroce, I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Answer (score 4):

Rather late to the party, but I just wanted to add that this kind of function is available in [ServiceStack.OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite):

```
class Poco 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Ssn { get; set; }
}

db.DropTable<Poco>();
db.TableExists<Poco>(); //= false

db.CreateTable<Poco>(); 
db.TableExists<Poco>(); //= true

db.ColumnExists<Poco>(x => x.Ssn); //= true
db.DropColumn<Poco>(x => x.Ssn);
db.ColumnExists<Poco>(x => x.Ssn); //= false
```

Please be aware, however, that this library is **not** free.

Comment: Do mention that this library is NOT free